Как заменить символы русской расскладки аналогичными символами английской расскладки и наоборот?
Нужно заменить ghbdtn => привет и наоборот. Вроде бы уже есть куча таких вопросов. Некоторые рекомендуют использовать кодировку. Пытался и особо ничего не получилось. Очень не хотелось бы просто хардкодить, но пока что вижу только этот вариант. Пишу на c#

тип приложения какой?

@aepot Пытаюсь написать приложение на winForms, а разве это важно?

В кириллице 33 буквы, в латинице 26, чем менять недостающие?

@Oopss это исправление ошибочной раскладки, очевидно. Что на кнопках на клаве нарисовано, тем и менять.

Про winforms возможно важно, да. Решение может включать в себя доступные там функции.

@aepot А, понял

Вот тут посмотрите.

Это может быть сделано следующим образом:
using System;
static class Program {
    static char[] ru, en;
    static char Ru2En(char ch) { return en[Array.IndexOf(ru, ch)]; }
    static void Main() {
        ru = "йцу".ToCharArray();
        en = "qwe".ToCharArray();
        char ch;
        while ((ch = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar) != 27) Console.WriteLine(Ru2En(ch));
    }
}

Нужно всю раскладку захардкодить в ru и en, и учесть регистр.
Если представить себе более широкую задачу, а именно сделать приложение для транслитерации по всем установленным в ОС раскладкам, тогда нужно было бы извлекать из настроек ОС данные об установленных раскладках и на основе этой информации делать преобразование.

Автор написал "Очень не хотелось бы просто хардкодить", поэтому предполагаю, что данное решение автору тоже очевидно. С хардкодом понятно, а не интереснее было бы поискать решение с использованием Keyboard Layouts из винды? Например берём символ, конвертим его в виртуальный с помощью данных одной раскладки, затем конвертим обратно с помощью данных другой раскладки.

@aepot Наверно, можно. Но это решение, судя по тому, как оно выглядит, самое короткое и эффективное.

@aepot если бы задача стояла более широко, а именно сделать транслитерацию по всем установленным в ОС раскладкам, тогда нужно было бы извлекать из настроек ОС раскладки. А если задача для одной фиксированной пары раскладок, то лучшее решение, я думаю, находится выше.

@rotabor в целом задача которую вы описали в коментарии и стоит.  Просто я сначала хотел раобраться хотя бы с английской и русской раскладкой. Однако я не совсем понял что вы имеете ввиду под "извлекать из настроек ОС раскладки".

Задача у вас в вопросе поставлена так: "Как заменить символы русской расскладки аналогичными символами английской расскладки и наоборот?", и наилучшее решение для неё выше. Если вам нужно что-то дргое, то задайте новый вопрос.

@rotabor Тогда можете показать "не лучшее" решение с извлечением из настроек ОС раскладок в этом вопросе.

Вряд ли. Мне это не пригодится. Сами покопайте в этом направлении. Для начала попробуйте найти Windows API, с этим связанный.
